# Equivalente a chartAt pero para números en lugar de cadenas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un número de un serial, por ejemplo 100101. que representa un artículo en especial pero también tengo el 200101, el 300101, el 400101 ... pero los documentos relacionados dependen de que el primer dígito sea 1, 2, 3 o 4.

Con `charAt` en una cadena puedo sacar el primer carácter, es decir tengo `'abcd'` y con `charAt(0)` me saca `'a'`, ¿existe algo similar al `charAt` pero para números?

Comment: Divide entre 100.000 y parsea a `int`. O convierte a cadena, coge el primer caracter y despues pasa a `int`

Comment: ¿Todos los números van a tener la misma longitud? Parece que sí, pero si no la tienen, ¿qué valor se consideraría el primero?

Comment: Es simple, si con `alpha.charAt(0)` obtienes el valor del primer carácter alfa, con `(""+number).charAt(0)` obtendras el valor del primer carácter numérico ;))...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo más sencillo, sería pasar el número a texto y quedarte con el primer carácter:

```js
let valor=100333;
let valorString=valor.toString();
console.log(valorString.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muchas veces no vemos las cosas que están delante de nosotros. SOS un MONSTRUO

Comment: que raro, el *respondida hace* de SO dice que pablo respondio antes

Comment: @Klaimmore Hummm, es verdad, ahora me sale también así, pero hace un rato no

Comment: Iba a poner eso como respuesta, pero creo que sería casi mejor como alternativa/edición a la tuya: ¿sería mejor con `valor.toString()` o haciendo `""+valor`? ¿y con `valorString.charAt(0)` o `valorString[0]`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Creo que eso daría para una pregunta aparte: creo que al concatenar con `+` dos elementos de tipo distinto, el intérprete llama a `.toString()` en ambos. Y desde ECMAScript 5 `charAt()` y los corchetes son dos formas válidas de acceder a posiciones, pero hay varios casos extremos en los que hay que andar con cuidado.

Comment: @PabloLozano cree una [pregunta sobre `charAt` y `[]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/159165/250), por si quieres echarle un ojo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias, te he puesto una respuesta con lo que he encontrado. Siguiendo con la temática lo mismo te interesa [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432321/javascript-unicodes-length-astral-symbols)

Answer (score 5):

Podría pasar el número a String y sacar el primer valor:

```js
var num = 200101;
var numero_string= num.toString();
var primerDigito= parseInt(numero_string.charAt(0));
console.log(primerDigito);
```

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo una solución sin convertir a string usando un poco de recursividad

```
function digitoMayor(num) {
  if (num > 9) {
    return digitoMayor(Math.trunc(num / 10));
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

o su forma acortada :)

```
function digitoMayor(num) {
  return num > 9 ? digitoMayor(Math.trunc(num / 10)) : num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como alternativa a los métodos anteriores (aunque realmente es otra manera de hacerlo similar a la que sugieren Pablo Lozano o Jonathan ch), podrías convertir el número en cadena si lo concatenas con una cadena vacía y luego acceder al primer elemento usando la notación de corchete. Algo como esto:

```js
let valor = 200101;
let primerDigito = (""+valor)[0];
console.log(primerDigito);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trabajar directamente con números seria:
primero obtener la cantidad de dígitos que tiene el numero e ir multiplicándolo por 10 por cada dígito.

luego dividimos el numero con la cantidad de dígitos-1 para obtener el primer dígito

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function getDigitos(n) {

  var digitos = 1;

  while (n > 0) {

    digitos = digitos * 10;
    n = n / 10;
    n = parseInt(n);
  }
  return digitos;
}

function getPrimerDigito(n) {
  return parseInt(n / (getDigitos(n) / 10));
}

console.log(getPrimerDigito(100101));
console.log(getPrimerDigito(200101));
console.log(getPrimerDigito(300101));
console.log(getPrimerDigito(400101));
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe incluso otra forma, utilizando el metodo `charAt` con `call` en una instancia que no es `String`:

Si bien no puedes usar

```
300101.charAt(0)
```

Puedes usar

```
String.prototype.charAt.call(300101, 0)
```

```js
console.log(String.prototype.charAt.call(300101, 0));
console.log(String.prototype.charAt.call(400101, 0));
```