# ¿Existen diferencias entre el acceso mediante charAt o corchete?

Tags: javascript

A partir de este [otra pregunta del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/159063/250) y sus respuestas, me surgió una duda sobre cómo acceder a los caracteres de una cadena.

Por un lado se sugiere usar [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charAt) (p.e. `cadena.charAt(0)`) para acceder al carácter que esté en la posición indicada, lo cual es correcto... pero yo siempre he usado la notación corchete (p.e. `cadena[0]`) para acceder al carácter de una posición concreta.

Haciendo algo de investigación online, he encontrado que el acceso mediante corchete no está soportado por versiones antiguas de IE (versiones que ya no se soportan oficialmente tampoco, por lo que no sería un problema), y haciendo [pruebas de rendimiento](https://jsperf.com/comparar-primer-digito/1) parece que el acceso con corchete obtiene resultados similares (o mejores) que `charAt` para un ejemplo como:

```js
let valor = 100333;
let valorString = valor.toString().charAt(0);
let valorCorchete = (valor.toString())[0];

console.log(valorString);
console.log(valorCorchete);
```

Entonces, ¿existe alguna diferencia entre leer un carácter mediante `charAt` o mediante corchetes? ¿hay casos en los que sería más recomendable usar uno sobre el otro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ECMAScript 3 no existía la opción de usar corchetes para acceder a posiciones de un string, fue añadido en la versión 5 del estándar. Por tanto, antes no se consideraba seguro usar corchetes porque algunos navegadores no lo soportaban.

Hoy día se considera el uso de los corchetes *sugar syntax*, un atajo para acceder a las posiciones de un string más breve que usar `.charAt()`. El comportamiento es *casi igual*, variando en casos extremos que no se suelen dar:

```js
let texto='hola';

console.log(texto.charAt(undefined));
console.log(texto[undefined]);

console.log(texto.charAt(NaN));
console.log(texto[NaN]);

console.log(texto.charAt(null));
console.log(texto[null]);

console.log(texto.charAt('a'));
console.log(texto['a']);
```

Supongo que el comprobar que la posición dada es un número legible (y en caso contrario asumir 0) es lo que hace que charAt() pueda ser más lento.

Algunos puristas consideran que lo correcto es usar .charAt(posición) para evitar la confusión con arrays y para evitar la tentación de intentar modificar un string de esa manera:

```js
let texto='hola';

console.log(texto[3]);
texto[3]='n'; //no falla, pero no tiene ningún efecto
console.log(texto[3]);
```

Los strings son inmutables y, además, no existe el tipo `char` en Javascript, con lo que aceptar modificar una posición de esa manera sería causa de muchos dolores de cabeza (¡imaginar que algo como `texto[2]='abc';` *tuviese algún efecto* debería asustarnos!)

Comment: otra diferencia entre ambas es que para indices fuera de rango `"abc".charAt(3)` retorna `""`, mientras que `"abc"[3]` retorna `undefined`

Comment: @Klaimmore Interesante. En ese caso (y los otros casos extremos que se ponen en la respuesta) casi pensaría que lo devuelto con los corchetes es más correcto que lo devuelto por `charAt`.